# How to get the value of clicked Gridview row on MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, gridview

I'm working on a MVC project. the problem that i need solution for is 
How can i get the value ( id or somthing) for a selected row on Gridview by a button click.

Selected can be by CheckBox or clicking on the row.

Comment: any exemple to show how ?

Comment: you can handle click events on your row or checkbox and store the selected row in a variable or mark it with css class or custom attribute. Css class could be a better option since you can apply the required styling to a selected row.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
txtid .Text  = Gridview1.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text;
```

Comment: Yeah bout how to send the value to the Controller  to run delete function? By using for ex Button click

Comment: http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article442-how-to-get-the-values-of-selected-row-from-a-gridview-using-aspnet.aspx // When you Click select finally you have to get the cell text and put it in a method which removes the object..

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `GridView.SelectedIndex` value to point to the selected
row.
Then use the `GridView1.Rows[SelectedIndex].Cells[1].Text` to get the
value inside the cell.

Comment: How to use GridView.SelectedIndex do u mean ?

and  how can i send the value to the Controller  to run delete function there?

Answer (score 0):

Try following code:

```
  string val="";
    for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.SelectedRows.Count; i++)
    {
       val=GridView1.SelectedRows[i].Cells[0].Value;
    }
```

Hope its helpful.

Comment: Yeah thans vut how to send this value to the controller by a button click for ex

Comment: define val [variable] as a global variable as i have done in my edit and then on button click just send the value to controller, variable is definitely going to have the value.[See the edit]

Comment: how can i make all the code without having any idea about your code?? I can just provide you direction.